# Timezone conversion

Tags: asp.net, timezone

How do I convert timezone from this format "03/03/2010 03:24:42 PM EST" to the current timezone in asp.net?

Comment: What language? ASP.NET is a web app framework.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for the [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131038.aspx) method. In general there's a lot of info on MSDN on this, [check it out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2h3syy57.aspx).

Or, wait-a-minute: The timezone in your example is "EST" -> Eastern Standard Time -> UTC -5. Is it really that simple?

Answer (score 0):

The details for converting from time zones can actually be ridiculously complicated, primarily because of daylight savings adjustment rules being different in different places, and different historical adjustment rules being applicable based on the date.

Fortunately there is an api method that claims to do all the difficult calculations for you:  System.TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime